# Gluing along closed subschemes by first embedding in an ambient space? (Request for help deciphering a reference to something well known.)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was skimming the beginning of Karl Schwede's paper ["Gluing Schemes and a Scheme Without Closed Points"](http://www.math.utah.edu/~schwede/Papers/SchemeWithoutPoints.pdf) and I read this sentence: "First it allows us to glue two abstract schemes together along a common closed subscheme without first embedding the schemes in any ambient space."

I don't know how embedding schemes in an ambient space will help with gluing along a closed subscheme - is there a classical method for doing this? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: My guess (and this is also hinted to after Corollary 3.9) is that you can construct the glueing $X \cup_Z Y$ if you have an ambient scheme $S$ with maps $X \to S$, $Y \to S$ such that the (scheme-theoretic) intersection of $X$ and $Y$ is $Z$.

Comment: I find it interesting that he constructs the fibred coproduct for ringed spaces first, as opposed to defining it for affine schemes (as the $\operatorname{Spec}$ of the fibred product $A \times_C B$) and then giving some glueing arguments. I wonder if there are any problems with the approach I am suggesting.